# AJAX POST from Firebug posts null values?

Tags: ajax, testing, firebug, security

I am trying to test the security of an application which uses AJAX requests.

I have tried using the Firebug terminal but the data does not make it through to the server.

Is this type of testing even possible in Firebug or would I need a different program?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/update',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(
    {extension:'x', mobile:'x', mobex:'x', altContact:'x', fax:'x', userid:'x', lcode:'x', desk: 'x'}
),
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data) {
  }
});
```

The back end is Python:

```
@jsonify
def updateExceptLocationAndDesk(self):
    print "Params:",request.params
```

The results is:

```
Params: UnicodeMultiDict([])
```

Comment: Check if you are getting response from the server or not using error block n ajax call

Comment: I am getting a response from the server, it is throwing a keyerror because request.params is null. I am also getting my results from the command shell which is serving the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working, but Im not sure how.

```
$.post(
        '/admin/update',
        {'extension':'123', 'mobile':'123', 'mobex':'123', 'altContact':'123', 'fax':'123', 'userid':'19700', 'lcode':'456456', 'desk': '123'},                    
        function (data)
        {
            if(data=='success')
            {
                $('#message').show();
                $('#message').html('Record successfully updated.');
                setTimeout(function(){$('#message').fadeOut('slow')}, 5000);
            }
        },
        'json'
        );
```

I dont think the jsonify changed anything. If anyone comes across this at least there is an answer here!